# Cannot compile some files after upgrading Node.js and Typescript (types conflict)

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, compilation, pnpm

I have a codebase with a few packages for the frontend written with `Typescript` and 1 for the backend written with `Typescript` and `Node.js`. I use `pnpm` package manager.

I had to upgrade Node.js version. After receiving some errors when starting my services, I also updated the version of the following packages (in the project and globally): `ts-node`, `tslib`, `typescript`, `@types/node`. These updates solved the issues and I was able to start and run the services but one package is failing to build specifically the files where the call to `URLSearchParams` is made. The problematic code in each file looks like this:

```
import {Fetcher, GetAllSearchParams, CreateCustomerInput, AllCustomer} from '../types';

export const makeSystemCustomers = (fetcher: Fetcher) => ({
  getAll: async (searchParams: GetAllSearchParams = {}): Promise<AllCustomer> => {
    const path = '/customers?' + new URLSearchParams(searchParams);
    return await fetcher({path});
  },
  ...
});
```

If I run `pnpm run build` I am getting:

```
Argument of type 'GetAllSearchParams' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | URLSearchParams | Record<string, string | readonly string[]> | Iterable<[string, string]> | readonly [string, string][] | undefined'
```

The weird part is that the type for `URLSearchParams` looks different in the editor than in the terminal. In the editor (I am using VSCode) its type shows like :

```
URLSearchParams | string | Record<string, string | ReadonlyArray<string>> | Iterable<[string, string]> | ReadonlyArray<[string, string]
```

And the type for `searchParams` is:

```
export type GetAllSearchParams = NodeJS.Dict<string> & {
  limit?: number;
  next_string?: string;
};
```

Package versions (before - now):

`Node.js`: 14.17.5 - 18.13.1

`@types/node`: 14.14.33 - 18.11.18

`ts-node`: 9.1.1 - 10.9.1

`tslib`: 1.14.1 - 2.4.1

`typescript`: 4.1.3 - 4.9.4

Comment: Is your editor set up to use your *project* version of Typescript, or its own? Make sure you set it to use the workspace version to ensure what you see in your editor and compiled code are the same (via the command pallete, the option is "Typescript: Select Typescript Version...")

Comment: can you cast it to `Record<string, string>` 
like `new URLSearchParams(searchParams as Record<string, string>)`

Comment: @JoshuaOpata I actually did just that after some closer investigation and that solved the problem :)